# Android combining or inheriting colors

Tags: android, android-xml

Is it somehow possible in Android to inherit or combine color values?

An example:

```
<color name="my_general_focused_color">#ff0000</color>
<color name="my_semi_transparent_focused_color">
    @color/my_general_focused_color ^ #44000000 
</color>
```

where the outcome here would be an xor of the two colors like `my_semi_transparent_focused_color == #44ff0000`

Any ideas? Alternatives? :)

Comment: No arithmetic operations on XML level, unfortunately. They would be useful in other contexts, too, but they're not available. You can do this programmatically, of course, and compute all your derived values in `Application.onCreate()` and store them there, but then, you'll also have to _assign_ them programmatically. But if you want to deploy this on a larger scale then I'd try to do it via compile-time XSLT preprocessing of Android XML resource files... Haven't tried it, though.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I feared. Grasping at straws here :)

I'm not too keen on preprocessing XML compile-time. That process is unstable/unreliable enough as it is already.

Doing it from within the code makes reading the styles difficult, and may lead to errors.

Maybe extending the aapt... Sounds like a larger project though... And with with SDK updates this isn't ideal either.
Just thinking out loud here :)

Comment: You're right, maintaining the XSLT involvement might not exactly be fun. One other way would be to have a `SmartViews` class with static helper functions and then easily derived `SmartTextView`, `SmartImgView` etc inner classes which deploy the helper methods to compute their colours from a newly introduced attribute for which you provide a parser. Subclassing all Android `View` classes would be a matter of a few lines for inflation and construction probably, once the helper methods are set up.

Comment: That could work, but I think it's overkill for my specific purpose. I have 500+ views and numerous custom views :-/

Comment: It's up to you to judge that. It seems like whether it pays or not depends on the number of different colours, in other words, the effort to change all the manually derived colours. Either way, I just started to like the parser idea. Maybe I'm going to do that one day. :) Anyway, good luck!